# No valid crumb was included in the request Jenkins 2.192 git hooks

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, githooks

I tried many solutions in the internet and still unable to fix this. In jenkins Global security I tick Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits with enable proxy compatibility. I also tried without Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits and it causes to creating crumb. My jenkins URL is also correct.

My post-receive file looks like this,

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get branch name from ref head

if ! [ -t 0 ]; then
  read -a ref
fi
IFS='/' read -ra REF <<< "${ref[2]}"
branch="${REF[2]}"

if [ "$branch" == "master" ]; then
crumb=$(curl -u "jenkins:1234" -s 'http://jenkins:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
curl -u "jenkins:1234" -H "$crumb" -X POST http://jenkins:8080/job/maven/build?delay=0sec

  if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "*** Ok"
  else
    echo "*** Error"
  fi
fi
```

Error msg is 
[HTTP ERROR 403](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtk3k.png)

Comment: So you're using a server-side post-receive hook to trigger a build in Jenkins? Have you considered using the GitLab Jenkins plugin and integration? Then you don't have to worry about this custom script and calling URLs yourself, etc.

Comment: interstng.. Let me try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I found unsafe answer :-). But it works. What I did is disable Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits and remove crumb related lines from the post-receive file. New post receive file looks like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get branch name from ref head

if ! [ -t 0 ]; then
  read -a ref
fi
IFS='/' read -ra REF <<< "${ref[2]}"
branch="${REF[2]}"

if [ "$branch" == "master" ]; then
#crumb=$(curl -u "jenkins:1234" -s 'http://jenkins:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
#echo"******************************"
echo "$crumb"
#echo"******************************"
curl -u "jenkins:1234" -H -X POST http://jenkins:8080/job/maven-job/build?delay=0sec

  if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "*** Ok"
  else
    echo "*** Error"
  fi
fi
```

Appreciate if someone could provide better answer.